# Filter breaks when adding it globally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, filter

I'm using [Luke Sampson's filter](http://lukesampson.com/post/471548689/entering-and-exiting-https-with-asp-net-mvc) in asp.net MVC3 called [ExitHttpsIfNotRequired], which can be applied to a controller or action and automatically redirects to HTTP if [RequireHttps] isn’t also applied.

This works perfectly when I apply it to a single controller. However, as I will be applying this to 99% of my controllers I decided to add it to my global filters:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new ExitHttpsIfNotRequiredAttribute());

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

It now continues to work for http:// pages, but as soon as I visit anything on https:// I get an error 500. I have tried debugging countless times but I can't seem to replicate the issue locally - does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! My main ssl controller was calling another **non-ssl** controller (using Html.Action) in the layout - an eventuality for which the filter is not set up for:

I fixed this by adding the following to Luke's [ExitHttpsIfNotRequired] filter:

```
// Abort if it's a child controller
if (filterContext.IsChildAction) return;
```